# How can I compute the Cartesian product of a vector with itself N times?

Tags: rust

I'm looking for a function with the signature `fn product(vector: &Vec<i32>, n: &i32) -> Vec<Vec<i32>>` or similar. An example:

```rust
assert_eq!(
    product(vec![1, 2, 3, 4], 2),
    [
        [1, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 3],
        [1, 4],
        [2, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [2, 3],
        [2, 4],
        [3, 1],
        [3, 2],
        [3, 3],
        [3, 4],
        [4, 1],
        [4, 2],
        [4, 3],
        [4, 4]
    ],
)
```

I have tried using [`iproduct`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.0/itertools/macro.iproduct.html) from the `itertools` crate:

```
use itertools::iproduct; // 0.10.0

fn product(vector: &Vec<i32>, n: &i32) -> Vec<Vec<i32>> {
    let mut result = Vec::new();

    for _ in 0..*n {
        result = iproduct!(result.iter(), vector.iter()).collect();
    }

    result
}
```

Which produces this error:

```
error[E0277]: a value of type `Vec<_>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `(&_, &i32)`
 --> src/lib.rs:7:58
  |
7 |         result = iproduct!(result.iter(), vector.iter()).collect();
  |                                                          ^^^^^^^ value of type `Vec<_>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=(&_, &i32)>`
  |
  = help: the trait `FromIterator<(&_, &i32)>` is not implemented for `Vec<_>`
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. What type do you expect `result` to be, exactly? For it to be the return value, it has to be `Vec<Vec<i32>>`, right? But then `iproduct!(result.iter(), vector.iter())` returns an `Iterator<Item = (&Vec<i32>, &i32)>` (you can see that by specifying the type of `result` explicitly) and it assigns a `Vec<(&Vec<i32>, &i32)>` to `result`, which can't work. So you need to `map` an `(&Vec<i32>, &i32)` to a `Vec<i32>` first.
2. At the start, `result` is empty so its product with anything is empty. It needs to contain a single element instead. What should that element be?
3. There is little point to taking `n` by reference; similarly, it's [preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-vec-vec-o) to accept a slice `&[i32]` instead of a `&Vec<i32>`

If you fix all of this, you get

```
S  
o  
m  
e  

s  
p  
o  
i  
l  
e  
r  

s  
p  
a  
c  
e  

f
o
r

y
o
u

t
o

t
r
y

y
o
u
r
s
e
l
f
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1ee37c4d537ed4966be8301c3fa6c4c6)

```rust
use itertools::iproduct;

fn product(vector: &[i32], n: i32) -> Vec<Vec<i32>> {
    let mut result: Vec<Vec<i32>> = vec![vec![]];

    for _ in 0..n {
        result = iproduct!(result.iter(), vector.iter())
            .map(|(v, x)| {
                let mut v1 = v.clone();
                v1.push(*x);
                v1
            })
            .collect();
    }

    result
}
```

I'd go with [`flat_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map) instead of using `iproduct` myself.